# Programming a randomization scheme, while loops

Tags: r, random, simulation, allocation

I'm trying to simulate a randomization process. I think I'll have to use a while loop, and I'm unfamiliar with how to best structure what I'm trying to accomplish in my R code.

Let's say I have 3 classes, a,b, and c in that I want to be distributed in a 3:2:1 ratio, respectively. A vector containing a minimally 'balanced' set of these classes in this ratio would look something like this:

```
class_1<-"a"
class_2<-"b"
class_3<-"c"

ratio_a<-3
ratio_b<-2
ratio_c<-1
min_set<-c(rep(class_1,ratio_a),rep(class_2,ratio_b),rep(class_3,ratio_c))
```

This minimum set would look something like this:

```
min_set
"a""a""a""b""b""c"
```

Let's then say I want to have `k` number of this minimally balanced set, I could create that like this:

```
block_1<-matrix(0,k,length(min_set))

for(i in 1:k)
  block_1[i,]<-min_set
```

This would create a new matrix with my `min_set`vector for `k` rows.

Let's now say I want to sample from `block_1` without replacement (a treatment allocation would be determined by the class (a,b,c) of the sample) This can be done as:

```
sample(as.vector(block_1),n,replace=F)
```

From here, I can enumerate all sampling outcome permutations of the `min_set` as (thanks to amonk):

```
myList <- permn(min_set)
all_out <- data.table(matrix(unlist(myList),byrow = T,ncol = 6))
```

All_out is a df with rows representing each permutation of the min_set. Here's where I'd like help.

Let's create a second block

```
#Create inactive urn
block_2<-vector('numeric',length=dim(block_1)[1]*dim(block_1)[2])
```

I would like to sample from `block_1` until I have sample one permutation of `min_set` (one of the rows from all out). My code would look something like this (not currently working):

```
while (block[2]!='any row of all_out'){
  for (i in 1:(dim(block_1)[1]*dim(block_1)[2]))
     block_2[i]<-sample(as.vector(block_1),i,replace=F)
}
```

Once I have achieved the `min_set` in `block_2`, I'd like to return the min_set back to block_1 from block_2, keeping p-6 samples (i.e. those not part of the min_set) in block_2.

Repeat until a prespecified number of allocations are made.

Answer (score 0):

So for a given set of characters:

```
 >min_set
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "c"
```

all the permutations are generated (respecting the *analogies* of characters per string):

```
library(combinat)
library(data.table) 

myList <- permn(min_set)
myDT <- data.table(matrix(unlist(myList),byrow = T,ncol = 6))

> myDT
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 1:  a  a  a  b  b  c
 2:  a  a  a  b  c  b
 3:  a  a  a  c  b  b
 4:  a  a  c  a  b  b
 5:  a  c  a  a  b  b
 ---                  
716:  a  c  a  a  b  b
717:  a  a  c  a  b  b
718:  a  a  a  c  b  b
719:  a  a  a  b  c  b
720:  a  a  a  b  b  c
```

Comment: @lecreprays you can add a more realistic approach such a case you describe but this time add some example data frames as well

Comment: I added some more examples. I'm trying to work up some example data as well, but hopefully my question is more clear now.